# C# Wpf Animation Projectile

Tags: c#

I just started using WPF and searched on how to do animations, there is many good tutorials but i can't seem to find the specific thing i need.

My goal is to create a small circle to start at a location and when a timer ticks move the circle smoothly towards another point(within 1 second). There is going to be new starting points and target points each tick.

As i said im fairly new to WPF so XAML is a new area for me, so i don't know how to animate the movement or if i should draw the circle or use an image. I don't even know if this is hard or an easy thing to do.

For reference im trying to make it look like the projectiles in this link: 
http://map.norsecorp.com/#/

Would appreciate any help or any google search words i should use.

/ Alexander

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to work with animations, WPF isn't the right tool for you.
I have done many projects in this direction in the past and i cant recommend WPF. You need to work with multiple threads and your code is getting messy very soon.  WPF is optimized for buisness solutions not for drawing circles. You can use Unity 3D. Its easy to learn and there are many examples out there.